# Make a map element blank, disappear (Google Maps JavaScript API, v3)

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-api-javascript-client

There are many calls for [help](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18509973/google-maps-api-showing-blank-map) with the maps API where a [blank](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20056434/google-maps-api-v3-works-but-is-blank) white div is [undesirable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34967378/blank-map-element-in-google-maps-javascript-api-v3). In my case it's desirable.

I know how to make a map appear.

```
map.setCenter(new google.maps.LatLng(latitude, longitude));
```

I know how to make directions appear.

```
directionsService.route(request, function(result, status) {
    if (status === google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
        directionsDisplay.setDirections(result);
    }
});
```

Occasionally I just want **the map element to "go white."** Later I want to put a map or directions back in there.

I've tried this:

```
$('#map').empty();
```

It works, but after that I can never make a map appear again. What's the correct way?

I suppose I could make and delete map instances but [this bug report](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/35821412) says each destroyed map instance leaks 2MB memory, and Google officially discourages the practice ([here](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/35821412#comment32) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10660672/673991)).  I'd really rather not overlay a white rectangle, or make the map display:none. Is there no *better* way?

(My application is a map next to an address entry form. When sufficient detail has been entered, a map automatically appears. If the field contents are deleted, the map goes blank again.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set the map `visibility` to `hidden`.

Better yet, use a class.

CSS:

```
.map-hide {
    visibility: hidden;
}
```

jQuery:

```
$('#map').addClass('map-hide');
$('#map').removeClass('map-hide');
```

JavaScript ([IE10+](http://caniuse.com/#feat=classlist)):

```
document.getElementById("map").classList.add('map-hide');
document.getElementById("map").classList.remove('map-hide');
```

Add the class to blank the map. Remove it when rendering the map.

Adding and removing a class is better in case multiple parts of the code turn visibility on or off for different reasons.

Setting a map's visibility to hidden is better than setting its display to none, which can permanently ruin map rendering. I saw one clue to this in the [docs](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/3.exp/reference#Map) about Map.fitBounds() breaking.

Answer (score 0):

I would just set the map div's innerHTML to "".

```
document.getElementById('map_canvas').innerHTML = "";
```

(but `$("#map_canvas").empty();` works as well)

Once you do that you need to recreate and reinitialize the map object.

```
map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), {
  center: new google.maps.LatLng(37.4419, -122.1419),
  zoom: 13,
  mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
});
```

[proof of concept fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/hd4cseg4/)

```js
function initialize() {
  var map = new google.maps.Map(
    document.getElementById("map_canvas"), {
      center: new google.maps.LatLng(37.4419, -122.1419),
      zoom: 13,
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    });
  var displayMap = true;
  google.maps.event.addDomListener(document.getElementById('btn'), 'click', function() {
    if (displayMap) {
      document.getElementById('map_canvas').innerHTML = "";
    } else {
      map = new google.maps.Map(
        document.getElementById("map_canvas"), {
          center: new google.maps.LatLng(37.4419, -122.1419),
          zoom: 13,
          mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
        });
    }
    displayMap = !displayMap;

  });
}
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, "load", initialize);
```

```css
html,
body,
#map_canvas {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px
}
```

```html
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js"></script>
<input type="button" id="btn" value="toggle map" />
<div id="map_canvas"></div>
```

Comment: I mentioned this goes against google advice.  See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10660672/673991) which quotes a video where googloids say "they don't really support use cases that involve creating/destroying successive map instances." Or did I misunderstand something?

Comment: A 2011 [bug report](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/35821412) "Destroying Google Map Instance Never Frees Memory" (about 2MB each) received an [official response](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/35821412#comment32) in 2015 "I'm labeling this as **won't fix**, because this is technically difficult. We're not really sure in how many places we're leaking."